# Key bindings disappear after changing JTable model

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` which is created as below with a default empty model.

If I change that data model by the external processing of a text file (CSV), and reset it using `RosterTable.setModel(...)`, the the standard key binding for TAB and Shift+TAB are lost.  The change of the `TableModel` is a pretty standard, and laid out below.

**So the symptom is**: A brand new `RosterTable` performs as expected, meaning that TAB moves one cell to the right, Shift + TAB moves one cell to the left and both wrap to the next/prev row at the ends of the table rows.  After the call to `setModel()`, TAB and Shift + TAB no longer function at all.
Why would the `InputMap` change when setting the `TableModel`?

**NOTABLY:** Other tables within the same application load their tables at instantiation by use of a serialized object.  These tables also function normally with the TAB and Shift + TAB keys.  Changing the data in the table "on the fly" by manual editing does not seem to affect the key bindings either.  It only seems to show errors when using `setModel`.

```
RosterTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

RosterTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
...
    },
    new String [] {
        "Callsign", "Close Time", "Notes", "Precedence", "Dest RI", "List Time", "Status", "Sent Time"
    }
) {
    Class[] types = new Class [] {
        java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
    };

    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return types [columnIndex];
    }
});

RosterTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
RosterTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
RosterTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
RosterScrollPane.setViewportView(RosterTable);
RosterTable.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
setRosterTableColumWidths(); // to resize columns to preferred widths
RosterTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN);
RosterTable.setGridColor(java.awt.Color.DARK_GRAY);
RosterTable.setShowGrid (true);
```

Then when the table data needs to be changed in a wholesale manner, the code to accomplish this looks like the following.  The first statement is the recipient of the output of a `FileChooser` open action.  `EMPTY` is a static empty String in case that is not abundantly obvious.

```
        File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String lineIn = null;
        int count = -1;
        Vector<Vector> data = new Vector<>();
        Vector<String> row = null;
        String[] tokens = null;
        String delim = ",";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            // skip all data before the roster itself
            while ((lineIn = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // call is the start of the header text line
                if (lineIn.startsWith("NCS:")) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // now process all roster lines until we get to BT
            while ((lineIn = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (lineIn.startsWith("BT")) {
                    // we found the end of the data
                    break;
                }
                count++;
                row = new Vector<>();
                tokens = lineIn.split(delim);
                if (tokens.length > 0) {
                    for (String token : tokens) {
                        row.add(token.equals(EMPTY) ? null : token);
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                        row.add(null);
                    }
                }
                data.add(row);
            }
            br.close();
            // now fill the rest of the rows with nulls so
            // empty rows may be filled by the user in the UI
            while (count < 100) {
                row = new Vector<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    row.add(null);
                }
                data.add(row);
                count++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StationManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StationManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        // reload the column labels from existing
        Vector<String> colsV = new Vector<>();
        TableModel tcm = RosterTable.getModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            colsV.add((String) tcm.getColumnName(i));
        }
        TableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(data, colsV);
        RosterTable.setModel(tm);
        setRosterTableColumWidths();
```

Once this method is complete, the table model is correct, but TAB, Shift+TAB, and ENTER no longer work the same as when the table model was first initialized.  TAB, Shift+TAB and ENTER put the highlighted cell into edit mode only.  The arrow keys function as normal.  Text may be typed into any cell per normal also.

Does the `JTable` care that I build a new model with `Vector` instead of `String[]`, etc.?  Doesn't sound logical to me.

Here is an SSCCE, and as noted in comments, it works as expected, so I am more confused now. ;)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class TableModelChange extends JFrame {

private JTable t = null;

public TableModelChange() {
    super();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 200);
    JButton loadModel = new JButton("Load New Model");
    loadModel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            loadModelButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    t = new JTable();
    t.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][]{
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String[]{
                "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7", "Col8"
            }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class[]{
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types[columnIndex];
        }
    });
    this.getContentPane().add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.getContentPane().add(loadModel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.pack();
}

private void loadModelButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Vector<Vector> data = new Vector<>();
    Vector<String> row = new Vector<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            row.add("A");
        }
        data.add(row);
    }
    Vector<String> colsV = new Vector<>();
    TableModel tcm = t.getModel();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        colsV.add((String) tcm.getColumnName(i));
    }
    t.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, colsV));
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TableModelChange tm = new TableModelChange();
            tm.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you changing the JTable data model?  Create one table model and add and / or remove rows from that data model.

Comment: I was considering that as well.  It would involve deleting the data in the model already, which is not too bad since max it is only 100 rows and 8 columns of `String`.  That way, I won't have to reset the column widths and such also.

Comment: But I also make use of a `tableChanged` handler on `TableModelEvent`s, so that complicates things a bit.

Comment: `Why would the InputMap change when setting the TableModel?` - It won't. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.  And fix your variables names while creating the `SSCCE`. Variables should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: The likely causes are, you're creating a new instance of `JTable`; the `JTable` on the screen isn't the one which you've applied the key bindings to; some other guess I've not thought of

Comment: @MadProgrammer, there is no new instance of JTable.  I create a Vector<Vector> of String for the data and Vector<String> for column names and do a setModel() on the original table object, as noted in the original text above.  I will add the actual model build and set into the question.

Comment: In the process of SSCCE now.  Interestingly, I cannot recreate the issue when simplifying the process using static data in the SSCCe.  I am beginning to suspect the TableModelListener somehow...or perhaps I didn't get this GUI on the EDT...hmmm..

Comment: SSCCE added, and it functions properly after a model change.  I have examined the content of the InputMap before and after model change as well as the ActionMap using a step debugger.  Nothing out of the ordinary, though they are layered due to ancestry so that can get interesting to trace.  Though less efficient, I may try @Gilbert Le Blanc 's suggestion at least as a sanity check and delete and add rows in the current model.

Comment: It works because you're not losing Key Bindings from a model change, since this won't cause that side effect. Something else is going on, and this means that you have to do more debugging.

Comment: I tried simply changing the rows of the existing model and I get the same result.  Interesting twist however:  I changed on the fly from Nimbus L&F to Metal L&F and the InputMap/ActionMap issues disappeared.  If I did the same data model change function in the Metal L&F the problem reappeared.  Then if I changed back to Nimbus, the problem once again went away....and so on.

Comment: ...and the SSCCE does not include L&F code, but it functions as expected.

Comment: So this makes me ponder, "I wonder if the L&F interaction is involved, so perhaps I should try to explicity re-set these KeyStroke bindings in the ActionMap just for grins??"  Details at 11.

Comment: More info:  I have two `JTable`s in the same GUI.  When I lose key bindings in the subject table, they are also lost on the other table.  This is definitely up the hierarchy somewhere.

Comment: It even happens when the GUI spawns another `JFrame` with a `JTable` in it.  This GUI is defaulted to Nimbus or Metal when created and I can change back and forth on the fly.  Doing so "fixes" the issue util the model is updated again.  I am going to turn off the plaf "feature" and use the default plaf and see what happens.

Comment: If I add a call to load the existing L&F after changing the `JTable` model,  the problem disappears.  **For now, that's the workaround**, but I would love to get to the bottom of this issue.  Suggestions on how/where to trace would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add a call to load the existing L&F after changing the JTable model, the problem disappears. For now, that's the workaround, but I would love to get to the bottom of this issue. Suggestions on how/where to trace would be welcome.